# Backup and restore Azure database using Azure Data Studio

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-data-studio

I have a database hosted on Azure and I have connected to it from mac machine using Azure Data studio. I want to take a backup of this database and then restore it in localhost to access it locally for better speed during development. I don't see any option to backup and restore the Azure database using Azure Data Studio. there were several options available in SQL server management studio on windows.

Suggestions, please.

Comment: Assuming it's an Azure SQL Database you can't use the `RESTORE` and `BACKUP` methods, you needs to use a bacpac or dacpac.

Comment: See [SQL Server dacpac extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/extensions/sql-server-dacpac-extension?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 1):

As stated by Larnu, yes that could be possible using DACPAC and BACPAC in Azure.

SQL Server DACPAC extension – [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-tier-applications/data-tier-applications?view=sql-server-ver15).

The wizard facilitates the creation and deployment of data-tier pieces that support your application by making it easier to manage dacpac and bacpac files. Check out MSFT documentation to learn more about utilising Data-tier apps, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/extensions/sql-server-dacpac-extension?view=sql-server-ver15#why-would-i-use-the-data-tier-application-wizard).

A DAC is a self-contained SQL Server database deployment unit that allows data-tier developers and database administrators to package SQL Server objects into a portable artefact known as a DAC package, sometimes referred to as a DACPAC.
A BACPAC is a similar artefact that contains both the database schema and the data contained in it.